# React Native get available height for content

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a custom component which needs its height to be set explicitely. I'm having trouble with calculating the available space on different devices.

The top bar is no problem cause I use the StatusBar height, but on the bottom, the iPhone X has some space for that "bar" and I don't know how to calculate this (I could match the device but maybe there are more devices with this space on the bottom).

Is there any way to calculate this? I'm using Expo btw.

Comment: could you provide your screen code?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean screen code?

Comment: Sorry I was meant to say custom component code. which you have created

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is your primary goal but here are my suggestions:

1. If you want to calculate the available height you can create a `View` with style `{flex:1}` then   use `onLayout` built-in function of a `View`. Here how it works:

   ```
   onLayout=({nativeEvent})=>{
      // Here is height
      console.warn(nativeEvent.layout.height)
   }

   <View style={styles.container}>
      <YourComponents/>
      {/*The part you want to calculate height*/}
      <View style={{flex:1}} onLayout={onLayout}/>
   </View>
   ```
2. If you want to just avoid the notch of the device you can use `SafeAreaView`. [Here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-safe-area-view) is the full documentation. PS. `react-native`'s built in `SafeAreaView` component has been moved to `react-native-safe-area-view`